# GPS won't stop updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm writing an iPhone application that uses GPS data. My problem is that the GPS never stops updating the locations (the arrow stays on the status bar) even if I kill the actual process. The only way to make it disappear is uninstalling the app, or disallowing it to use location in system settings.

This is how I create the location manager:

```
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = regionTracker;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In my app delegate, I run these two rows both in applicationWillTerminate: and applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
   [self.viewController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   [self.viewController.locationManager setDelegate:nil];
```

I nil the delegate because I saw some example where they did that, but should it really be needed?

Comment: Does the locationManager property provide a non-nil value within those app delegate methods?

Comment: Yes. I just tested firing a breakpoint if it is nil, no dice. Grateful for more help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same as milonet mentioned, in my case I needed to call stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in addition to the stopUpdatingLocation.

Comment: This worked to solve same problem for me. Don't forget to Upvote @milonet's answer too, if only because his comment below his answer was the first suggestion of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect something funny is going on with the retain/release lifecycle of your CLLocationManager object.

In the delegate, you're treating it like a property. In the viewController you're treating it like an iVar.

I'd rather you assign it to `self.locationManager` rather than `locationManager`. Assuming that's a named property with the `retain` setter semantic, and then you `release` it in your viewController's `-dealloc` method (possibly after calling `stopUpdatingLocation` on it), you should be good to go.

I've seen this same behavior myself, though, the first time I played around with CoreLocation right after 4.0 and backgrounding came along. I thought there was something wrong with my battery, because I'd just gotten an iPhone 4. Turns out I was just churning CoreLocation whether my app was running or not.

Comment: You are raising a good point and I should've done that from the beginning. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. GPS still stays on. I even tried releasing and setting the locationManager to nil and it still stays on. 

Also, what does stopUpdatingLocation actually do, when you need to release the location manager anyway? (which doesn't work for me either, but still)

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the cause of this. In an earlier stage of the project I had used the region function of iOS 4, which registered global regions of the system associated with the application identifier.

Solution - make a new project.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem, the location manager stay on always!
i have try to dealloc all but the gps stay on.. the only solution for turn off the gps is delete the app!

Comment: Are you using the region functions of iOS 4+?

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i misread your comment. i'm not using a region functions of ios 4.+

Comment: Okay, then I do not know the problem. Mine was related to the OS keeping track of regions registered by the application, as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: I found the solution, i have put a method [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] above [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation].. the gps stop works fine:D after the first build with this method i remove this and the app continue to work correctly..

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me. I was using a mapView with **userlocation activated**.I deallocated locationmanager as usual and the GPS still was active. I disabled that option and the gps stopped when it was supposed to.