# iOS 5.1 CoreLocation, location service icon not disappearing

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am tracking users location in my app, and I am stopping updates when I receive the first location update. The idea is to only get a "snapshot" of the users location once, not actually track the users movement.

However in iOS 5.1 on device and simulator, the location service icon at the top right of the screen doesn't disappear after the tracking started.

On iOS 5.0 (could only test in simulator), the icon appears and disappears as expected.

Does anyone know of any bugs that may affect CoreLocation in iOS 5.1 ?

I found someone else reporting something very similar, however he says if you force kill the app in multitasking bar, the icon is removed, mine persists, this is even when the app is not running at all.

Also (after killing the app), if I go into locations services in settings, my app is lit up purple and I can turn on or off, toggling the location icon at the top with no problem.

Check out this guy: http://bendodson.com/weblog/2012/03/14/ios-5-1-location-services-bug/

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this behavior you describe is the precisely what it's supposed to do if you use the significant change service, but not if you use the standard service. Do you remember which you were using?

Comment: Yes I was using -startUpdatingLocation not monitoring significant changes, it doesn't do this anymore. Maybe it was an issue with the iOS SDK at the time, or probably fixed as of iOs 5.1.1. The problem was in the simulator and on the iPad running iOS 5.1

Answer (score 5):

The traditional method:
`[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`
is not enough. You must also add:
`[locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499594/gps-wont-stop-updating) question.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made this question because I wasn't observing the same behaviour with iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1, hence the iOS 5.1 question. It was a bug in 5.1.

Comment: This answer is valid and necessary for iOS v6.x also.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that it takes a while for it to disappear (about 10 seconds). You might need to stop updating location and set the delegate to nil when the view disappears:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController]) {
        // Popping the view
        NSLog(@"MyViewController isMovingFromParentViewController");
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Note:** This code is iOS 5 only, and only triggers when the view is being dismissed and going back to the parent view. Adjust accordingly.

Just an aside, but you shouldn't rely on the first location you get back from the location manager, unless you've tested it for newness. You might get an old, cached location back.

Comment: unfortunately I'm doing this, and I'm NSLogging the callbacks so I'm sure it's happening.

Comment: And is it staying there for more than 10 seconds?

Comment: it's staying there forever ;) even after I kill it from the multitasking bar - funny thing is I'm not registering for background location services of any kind

Comment: I've seen this happen too lately. I can't remember how I made it go away, but I'd say turn off (all) location services, delete your app, restart the phone and try again.

Comment: The funny thing is I could understand the device getting messed up and caching things etc but the simulator also does this in iOS 5.1

Comment: Well the 10 second thing seems to be standard for all apps. Try opening any location app (e.g. Maps, Runkeeper) and closing it. The never-disappearing location arrow is a bug of some kind, possibly in the framework.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10287/discussion-between-daniel-and-nevan-king)

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is to only get a "snapshot" of the users location once, not actually track the users movement.

Also just want to get a snapshot. After calling

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

on iPhone4S - iOS 5.1.1 the navigation icon does not disappear immediately but with a delay of approximately 10 seconds. Furthermore, I sometimes receive another location update after calling stopUpdatingLocation.

Setting the location manager's delegate to nil is not necessary in order to get the navigation icon disabled.